# Direct use of 1/0 in V8 engine

Tags: javascript, python, v8, pyv8

I first thought it is python since the file is named macros.py. But some say it is not.

[This](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/2fc2cb99f52974d0743610189213a94585c30ac6/src/js/macros.py#L173) part of the v8 engine came to the point in the middle of another discussion.

```
# Constants.  The compiler constant folds them.
define INFINITY = (1/0);
```

I haven't seen anything like this in another language. What is the mechanism of this language (py?/js?) to allow such an expression?

Comment: Python has no `define` statements. What you have is *not Python code*.

Comment: This is in a macros.py file, but it doesn't seem to actually have anything to do with Python. It's really a question about the V8 rendering engine.

Comment: I'm sorry if not - but this is from v8/src/js/macros.py

Comment: Ok I edited the question.

Comment: Yes I noticed that now. Thanks. Did you see that in js `Infinity + Infinity = Infinity` thought `Infinity - Infinity = Nan` ?

Comment: @nos - Can you add the JS perspective of 1/0 as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

The line is not valid Python syntax. The Python language has no concept of `const` types, nor is there any `macro` syntax.

The `.py` extension on that file is highly misleading; there is only one line that may or may not contain actual Python syntax:

```
# Macros implemented in Python.
python macro CHAR_CODE(str) = ord(str[1]);
```

The file is actually parsed by a [Python script](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/6413ef4e632e425195beb4ab0ceefe3b308c51e9/tools/js2c.py), so it is, at best, a custom domain-specific language. The macros that are not marked as Python code with `python macro`, appear to be used to convert *JavaScript* code to character arrays, judging by the comment at the top:

```
# This is a utility for converting JavaScript source code into C-style
# char arrays. It is used for embedded JavaScript code in the V8
# library.
```

In *JavaScript* code, `(1/0)` produces float infinity:

```js
> (1/0)
Infinity
```

while in Python code this raises an exception:

```
>>> 1/0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

but you don't need such tricks as you can just use `float('inf')` if you really needed to refer to infinity.

Comment: The last sentence makes a lot of sense. I'll keep the question open for a while before choosing the answer.